# como aumentar de tamaño un modal en asp.net?

Tags: html5, asp.net, bootstrap, datatables, modal

si alguien me puede ayudar como hago para que el datatable se acome al modal, adjunto el codigo del modal y una imagen de como queda desprorcionado, no estoy usando CSS ni nada, solamente uso el datatable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo del modal ya agrege el "LG" pero no se adapta al datatable

```
<!-- Modal vista datos -->
<div class="modal fade" id="FormModalVista" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tiendas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


                <div class="row" style="margin:20px">

                    <table class="display responsive" id="myTable2" style="display: block;overflow-x: auto;white-space: nowrap;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombres</th>
                                <th>IDC</th>
                                <th>CA_NROCUENTA</th>
                                <th>CA_SUCURSAL</th>
                                <th>REGION</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que versión de bootstrap es ? Si es **bootstrap 5**, te falta el siguiente ajuste:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
   ...
  </table>
 </div>
```

Podés revisar más información en **[table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)** bootstrap5.

Comment: Gracias, el modal no se agrando pero el datatable se adapto, ya es algo

Comment: Todas las medidas estan en este lugar si querés revisar y usar el que más te ayude: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/